# Unable to run the app on IOS device

Tags: xcode, titanium, titanium-mobile, code-signing, titanium-alloy

I have created a sample titanium project, I am able to run my app on emulator. But when i try to deploy the same device I'm getting the following error,

```
[ERROR] :  Error details: Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Plan India Feedback App”) were found.
[ERROR] :  Error details: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
```

Can any one suggest me what is the issue and how to resolve the same.

```
Phone version is: 6.1.6
Emulator version: 8.1
```

Comment: Do you have a paid for developer license? They cost $99 a year and are required to run any apps on a physical device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates that your app id and Provisioning profiles dont match.Please make them same and you would be good to go

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can we match both id's same. While creating the project? Please explain me more. I'm new to IOS app development

Comment: Try this tutorial https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Deploying+to+iOS+devices

Comment: Yeah I tried the same link. My app id in provision profile is: Plan India Feedback App. So what Id should i need to give for project id.

Comment: I am trying to creating the titanium project